# Процент просмотра видео

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, api, видео, скрипт

Есть собственный внутренний сайт (портал). Если ли какая-то возможность получить информацию о том, сколько процентов (или секунд) видео просмотрел пользователь.
**Видео не с youtube**, а находится на внутреннем сервере.

p.s.: на сколько знаю, для ютюба есть youtubeAPI. Нужно что то подобное наверное

Всем заранее спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Отследите событие `playing` в видео. Оно срабатывает, когда пользователь запустил видео. После того, как событие произошло отправляйте данные на сервер, например раз в секунду, о том, что пользователь просматривает видео. Отправку прекратить, если сработает событие `pause`. Так же отправка прекратиться сама, если пользователь закроет ваш сайт. На сервере смотрите сколько запросов пришло с каждого ip. Количество запросов - это количество секунд, которое пользователь просматривал ваше видео

Comment: Спасибо! этот вариант мне подходит